# Apache Ignite: How do I fix the "Unknown pair" error when using a StreamReceiver?

Tags: java, c#, ignite

How do I fix the following serialization error when using a DataStreamer with a StreamReceiver? I am guessing that it is not able to find the class when deserializing the `RowStreamReceiver`.

Error: `SEVERE: Failure in Java callback class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Platform error:Apache.Ignite.Core.Binary.BinaryObjectException: Unknown pair [platformId=1, typeId=113114]`

I'm using Apache Ignite 2.0, and I am trying to employ the same kind of code demonstrated in this test:
https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/Apache.Ignite.Core.Tests/Dataload/DataStreamerTest.cs#L436

I've tried adding the assembly to the configuration, but that didn't seem to help. `config.Assemblies.Add(typeof(RowStreamReceiver).Assembly.FullName);`

Here's the relevant code:

DataStreamer:

```
using (var ds = m_ignite.GetDataStreamer<string, IBinaryObject>(CacheName)) {
    ds.AllowOverwrite = true;
    ds.Receiver = new RowStreamReceiver(); // If I comment this out, the error goes away
    Parallel.ForEach(rows.Select((r, i) => new KeyValuePair<long, string>(i, r)), r => {
        var pair = BuildRow(r.Key, r.Value);
        ds.AddData(pair);
    });
}
```

StreamReceiver:

```
[Serializable]
public class RowStreamReceiver : IStreamReceiver<string, IBinaryObject> {
    public void Receive(ICache<string, IBinaryObject> cache, ICollection<ICacheEntry<string, IBinaryObject>> entries) {
        var bin = cache.Ignite.GetBinary();
        cache.PutAll(entries.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => {
            var builder = bin.GetBuilder(x.Value);
            SetColumnFields(builder);
            return builder.Build();
        }));
    }

    private static void SetColumnFields(IBinaryObjectBuilder builder) {
        /* logic to set fields */
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Jul 07, 2017 11:25:22 AM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
SEVERE: Failure in Java callback class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Platform error:Apache.Ignite.Core.Binary.BinaryObjectException: Unknown pair [platformId=1, typeId=113114] ---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.JavaException: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Unknown pair [platformId=1, typeId=113114]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.binary.PlatformBinaryProcessor.processInStreamOutStream(PlatformBinaryProcessor.java:119)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformTargetProxyImpl.inStreamOutStream(PlatformTargetProxyImpl.java:155)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackUtils.inLongLongLongObjectOutLong(Native Method)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackGateway.dataStreamerStreamReceiverInvoke(PlatformCallbackGateway.java:464)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.datastreamer.PlatformStreamReceiverImpl.receive(PlatformStreamReceiverImpl.java:100)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerUpdateJob.call(DataStreamerUpdateJob.java:137)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.localUpdate(DataStreamProcessor.java:382)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.processRequest(DataStreamProcessor.java:301)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.access$000(DataStreamProcessor.java:58)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor$1.onMessage(DataStreamProcessor.java:88)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1257)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:885)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$2100(GridIoManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$7.run(GridIoManager.java:802)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unknown pair [platformId=1, typeId=113114]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:385)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.binary.PlatformBinaryProcessor.processInStreamOutStream(PlatformBinaryProcessor.java:113)
        ... 16 more

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.UnmanagedCallbacks.Error(Void* target, Int32 errType, SByte* errClsChars, Int32 errClsCharsLen, SByte* errMsgChars, Int32 errMsgCharsLen, SByte* stackTraceChars, Int32 stackTraceCharsLen, Void* errData, Int32 errDataLen)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.IgniteJniNativeMethods.TargetInStreamOutStream(Void* ctx, Void* target, Int32 opType, Int64 inMemPtr, Int64 outMemPtr)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.PlatformTarget.DoOutInOp[TR](Int32 type, Action`1 outAction, Func`2 inAction)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryProcessor.GetType(Int32 id)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.Marshaller.GetDescriptor(Boolean userType, Int32 typeId, Boolean requiresType)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.ReadFullObject[T](Int32 pos)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.TryDeserialize[T](T& res)  at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.Deserialize[T]()    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.ReadBinaryObject[T](Boolean do Detach)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.TryDeserialize[T](T& res)  at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.BinaryReader.Deserialize[T]()    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Datastream.StreamReceiverHolder.InvokeReceiver[TK, TV](IStreamReceiver`2 receiver, Ignite grid, IUnmanagedTarget cache, IBinaryStream stream, Boolean keepBinary)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Datastream.StreamReceiverHolder.Receive(Ignite grid, IUnmanagedTarget cache, IBinaryStream stream, Boolean keepBinary)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.UnmanagedCallbacks.DataStreamerStreamReceiverInvoke(Int64 memPtr, Int64 unused, Int64 unused1, Void* cache)    at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.UnmanagedCallbacks.InLongLongLongObjectOutLong(Void* target, Int32 type, Int64 val1, Int64 val2, Int64 val3, Void* arg)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformProcessorImpl.loggerLog(PlatformProcessorImpl.java:497)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackUtils.inLongLongLongObjectOutLong(Native Method)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.callback.PlatformCallbackGateway.dataStreamerStreamReceiverInvoke(PlatformCallbackGateway.java:464)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.datastreamer.PlatformStreamReceiverImpl.receive(PlatformStreamReceiverImpl.java:100)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerUpdateJob.call(DataStreamerUpdateJob.java:137)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.localUpdate(DataStreamProcessor.java:382)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.processRequest(DataStreamProcessor.java:301)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.access$000(DataStreamProcessor.java:58)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor$1.onMessage(DataStreamProcessor.java:88)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1257)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:885)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$2100(GridIoManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$7.run(GridIoManager.java:802)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: How many nodes do you have? How do you start other nodes?

Comment: I am running one server node and one client node on the same local machine that I am developing on.

Comment: How do you start the server node?

Comment: The Client and the Server are both c# console programs referencing the same DLLs with the Apache Ignite NuGet package. I'm using a programmatic configuration with default settings except for adding two BinaryTypeConfigurations. config.BinaryConfiguration.TypeConfigurations.Add(new BinaryTypeConfiguration(typeof (Table)) { Serializer = new BinaryReflectiveSerializer() }); config.BinaryConfiguration.TypeConfigurations.Add(new BinaryTypeConfiguration(typeof (Column)) { Serializer = new BinaryReflectiveSerializer() });

Comment: What if you comment out all Receive method contents? Will it still fail?

Comment: May be you can upload the whole solution somewhere like GitHub so I can take a look? I'm trying to reproduce the problem, but it works for me.

Comment: The solution is too big, but I'll create a smaller reproducer to see if I still get the same error. If it does, I'll upload that to github so you can take a look. I'll report back when I'm done.

Comment: Here's my github repo example: https://github.com/charlie430/IgniteStreamReceiverTest. However, I get a slightly different error "Unknown type ID" instead of "Unknown pair".

Comment: I've added a reference from Server project to Client project and the error went away. This is because `RowStreamReceiver` class is not available on server, there is no way to execute the code which is not present.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem in my example. Turns out the real problem was with how I got the DataStreamer. In my example, I did it right, but in my original project, I didn't. The correct way is to use KeepWithBinary. var ldr = ignite.GetDataStreamer<string, object>(CacheName).WithKeepBinary<string, IBinaryObject>() instead of var ldr = m_ignite.GetDataStreamer<string, IBinaryObject>(CacheName)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Unknown pair" issue is caused by not using GetDataStreamer correctly. My cache was originally created like this:

```
ignite.GetOrCreateCache<string, object>(cacheConfig)
```

so when getting the DataStreamer, I needed to use the same types, and then use KeepWithBinary

```
var ds = m_ignite.GetDataStreamer<string, object>(CacheName).KeepWithBinary<string, IBinaryObject>()
```

Answer (score 1):

`typeId=113114` is for `Row` class name. Looks like somewhere in `RowStreamReceiver` you try to deserialize such an object, but a class can't be found.

Can you attach the debugger to the server node and see where the exception is thrown?